# Better code implementation when mapping in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React and I was wondering if there is there a better way of writing the following function while maintaining same functionality?  Any help is much appreciated.

```
    let temp;
          temp= this.state.persons.map(person=> {
            if (person.id == this.person.id) {
              person.userInput= this.state.userInput;
              person.secondInput= this.state.secondInput;
              return person;
            } else {
              return person;
            }
```

Comment: Side note, there's a problem with this in that you're mutating the state. When mapping over an array of objects, the loop variable you get access to (in this case `person` ) is a *reference* to the _actual_ object in the array, not a copy of it. So when you do `person.userInput= this.state.userInput;` you are directly mutating the person in the state. Direct state mutations in React are a no no (a quick Google search can give you some great explanations as to why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Like Jayce444 mentioned, State in ReactJs cannot be modified directly, which means `person.userInput = this.state.userInput` doesn't work. You should use `this.setState()` instead.
- `Array.prototype.findIndex()`will return index which element satisfies callback function test. Reference to [findIndex_MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Using `findIndex()`maybe more elegant than `map()`.

```
const index = this.state.persons.findIndex(person=>person.id===this.person.id)
const tmpPersons = [...this.state.persons]
tmpPersons[index].userInput= this.state.userInput;
tmpPersons[index].secondInput= this.state.secondInput;
this.setState({persons:tmpPersons})
```

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything bad about your implementation per se. You could save a couple lines by just returning person regardless of whether you add/modify the `userInput` and `secondInput` props.

```
temp = this.state.persons.map(person => {
  if (person.id == this.person.id) {
    person.userInput = this.state.userInput;
    person.secondInput = this.state.secondInput;
  }
  return person;  
}
```